# Where were the Straits dollars printed?

Tags: currency, malaysia, brunei, singapore

From the information I gathered, the banknotes of the [Straits dollar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straits_dollar) were printed by Thomas De La Rue & Company, Limited, a firm based in London. Were the banknotes of the Straits dollar printed in Britain, in India, or in the Straits Settlements?

Comment: The Wikipedia entry for [De La Rue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_La_Rue) only mentions manufacturing locations in the UK, so I'd imagine they were printed in Britain.

Comment: @SteveBird The modern day De La Rue has manufacturing locations in the UK, Kenya, and Sri Lanka. It may have been different in the past (i.e. 100+ years ago).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They were printed in the UK.

The Straits Dollar was initially printed by Thomas de la Rue of London at their UK plants from 1901 until 1930:

[image: de la Rue]

and later, from 1931 to 1935, by Bradbury Wilkinson at their plant in New Malden in Surrey:

[image: Bradbury]

The Straits Dollar was replaced by the [Malayan dollar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malayan_dollar) in 1939, at an exchange rate of 1:1

---

In fact, even after independence, Singapore  currency notes  continued  to be  printed in the UK right up until 1984:

> Singapore’s currency notes were initially printed in the British plants of Bradbury Wilkinson & Co Ltd and Thomas De La Rue Ltd. In 1984, Thomas De La Rue established a plant in Jurong for the printing of Singapore currency notes

- [History of Singapore currency](http://eresources.nlb.gov.sg/infopedia/articles/SIP_2016-03-09_114438.html)